# More effective methods for transforming to normality

Tags: data-transformation, normality-assumption

I'm in a field that is overly concerned with transforming non-normal variables in an attempt to make them normal. However, it's also generally recognized that the standard transformations (e.g. log, square root, inverse, arc-sin) rarely result in normally distributed samples.
It recently occurred to me that it would be pretty easy to transform continuous data to obtain a normal distribution in the following way:

Calculate the percentile for each value.

Then use the inverse cumulative distribution function for the normal distribution to transform the percentiles to a normally distributed variable.

However, I've never seen this done. Is there a reason why people continue to use log/square-root transformations rather than something like this? (I'm familiar with the alternatives to OLS approaches that don't require this assumption. I'm more curious about the transformation itself)

Comment: this is sometimes called "normal score transformation", e.g. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geostatistical-analyst/normal-score-transformation.htm; https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2921808/

Comment: There's a lurking question concerning the intended use and reliability of such a precisely determined transformation, due to its sensitivity to the data you have: unless you have a tremendous amount of data (and then what's the point of the transformation in the first place?), this probably amounts to a gross overfitting--it's an inherently uncertain assessment of the true underlying distribution.  If you use this transformation for either explanation or prediction, remember that you have to stick with it and explain and predict all future data in terms of that transformation.

Comment: I believe it's very similar in some circumstances to doing classic rank-based (Wilcoxon, Mann-Whitney, etc.) tests, because by definition it retains *only* the information on ranks.